# Group by Account Code

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

[image]

I want result sum of credits , debits and balances Code wise but i am worried how to use group by Account code  of all Company divisions

```
Select 'All Companies' as DivisionNameEn,
        a.LF_CompanyDivisionID,
        a.AccountCode as code,
        a.AccountNameEn as name,
        sum(ISNULL(Credit,0) - ISNULL(Debit,0)) as balance,
        sum(ISNULL(Credit,0)) as credit,
        sum(ISNULL(debit,0)) as debit 
        from View_ChartOfAccount a 

                                group by a.AccountCode
```

it is giving me error

Column 'View_ChartOfAccount.LF_CompanyDivisionID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Have you tried joining table to self?

Comment: i have tried this one Select 'All Companies' as DivisionNameEn,
  a.LF_CompanyDivisionID,
  a.AccountCode as code,
  a.AccountNameEn as name,
  sum(ISNULL(Credit,0) - ISNULL(Debit,0)) as balance,
  sum(ISNULL(Credit,0)) as credit,
  sum(ISNULL(debit,0)) as debit 
  from View_ChartOfAccount a 
  
        group by a.AccountCode ,a.LF_CompanyDivisionID ,a.AccountCode ,a.AccountNameEn ,LF_CompanyDivisionID

Comment: What does "i am worried how to use group by" mean? You should include your attempted query in the question instead of a comment as the formatting comments if horrific.

Comment: The error msg is **clear**, you need to add all the columns not contained in an aggregate function from the `SELECT` statement to the `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like that;

```
select Code, sum(balance), sum(credit), sum(debit) from 
table 
where DivisionNameEn = 'All Companies'
group by Code
```

`sum` calculations per `Code` and apply where clause for `All Companies`

Comment: Select 'All Companies' as DivisionNameEn,
  a.LF_CompanyDivisionID,
  a.AccountCode as code,
  a.AccountNameEn as name,
  sum(ISNULL(Credit,0) - ISNULL(Debit,0)) as balance,
  sum(ISNULL(Credit,0)) as credit,
  sum(ISNULL(debit,0)) as debit 
  from View_ChartOfAccount a 
  
        group by a.AccountCode 
 but showing me error Column 'View_ChartOfAccount.LF_CompanyDivisionID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: What is the desired output ?